# C++/CLI error: 'a value type of "int" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "Department ^"'

Tags: c++-cli

My problem is that on the line just above "return temp;" in my CreateNewDepartment function I get a weird compile error (red underline in Visual Studio). When I mouse over the compile error text ("deptId,") in "Department^ temp(deptId, var[0], var[1]);" the pop-up tip says:

```
a value type of "int" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "Department ^"
```

Here is my code to create a new  object:

```
Department^ CreateNewDepartment(SQLRETURN retCode, SQLHANDLE hStmt)
{
    int deptId;
    String^ Name;
    String^ Location;

    System::String^ bufN;
    char buf[256];
    SQLINTEGER numBytes;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        retCode = SQLGetData(
            hStmt,
            i,           // COLUMN NUMBER of the data to get
            SQL_C_CHAR,  // DATA TYPE that you expect to receive
            buf,         // BUFFER to put the data that you expect to receive
            255,         // BUFFER size in bytes (-1 for null terminator)
            &numBytes    // SIZE in bytes of data returned
        );

        if (CHECK(retCode, "SqlGetData", false))
        {
            bufN = gcnew String((char *)buf);
            if (i == 1)
            {
                std::string s = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(bufN);
                deptId = std::stoi(s, nullptr, 0);
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                Name = bufN;
            }
            else if (i == 3)
            {
                Location = bufN;
            }
        }
    }
    Department^ temp(deptId, Name, Location);
    return temp;
}
```

Department is defined thus:

```
ref class Department
{
private:
    int _deptId;
    String^ _deptName;
    String^ _deptLocation;

public:
    Department(int id, String^ deptName, String^ deptLocation);
    <...snip...>

}
```

And the cstr and set functions:

```
Department::Department(int id, String^ deptName, String^ deptLocation)
{
    setDeptId(id);
    setDeptName(deptName);
    setDeptLocation(deptLocation);
}

void Department::setDeptId(int id)
{
    _deptId = id;
}

void Department::setDeptName(String^ name)
{
    _deptName = name;
}

void Department::setDeptLocation(String^ location)
{
    _deptLocation = location;
}
```

Sorry if this is a simple error or dumb question, but I'm new to CLI.

Answer (score 0):

```
Department^ temp(deptId, Name, Location);
```

Apparently should have been:

```
Department^ temp(gcnew Department(deptId, Name, Location));
```

Although I have no idea why. lol

Comment: The first syntax would be correct without the `^`, for stack semantics. The second syntax is more commonly seen as `Department^ temp = gcnew...;`. Remember that `^` is analogous to `*`, variables are initialized with (gc)new.